# Which objects do not go to the Recycle Bin upon deletion?

Tags: account-teams

I'm working on a workaround for the lack of Trigger ability on the AccountTeamMember by writing a job that monitors creations and deletions. I'm finding out that AccountTeamMember seems to not go to the recycle bin upon deletion, instead it just is gone (even though there is an isDeleted field that I can query for with ALL ROWS).

I'm trying to verify that this is expected, and if so if there is a list of objects that isDeleted would be useless for in APEX code.

This was the query I was trying to run:

```
SELECT UserId, AccountId, TeamMemberRole, IsDeleted FROM AccountTeamMember ALL ROWS
```

I also verified deleting in the UI did not show anything in the Recycle Bin.

What is particularly strange is that if you delete the Account, the AccountTeamMembers show up in a query with IsDeleted = true (presumably in case you want to undelete the Account).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an item to appear in the Recycle Bin, it must meet three criteria:

1. It must be soft-deletable (the Undeletable flag is set to true).
2. It must be able to exist independently of its parent record (e.g. OpportunityLineItem will never appear in the Recycle Bin, but an Opportunity may). *Custom objects are always considered "independent", even if it has a cascade delete from a master-detail relationship.
3. It must have been explicitly deleted (e.g. not from a standard cascade soft-delete). For example, deleting an account will delete all contacts on the account, but those contacts won't appear in the Recycle Bin, because you cannot restore them without restoring the account.

Note that a record's appearance (or lack thereof) in the Recycle Bin does not accurately indicate if the record *may* be recovered. You can undelete the parent record in cases where a cascade delete was the result, and you can undelete some items that won't appear in the Recycle Bin at all.

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with all objects with the ["undeletable"](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_instance_methods.htm) = false.

```
List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().values();
for(Schema.SObjectType t : gd){
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult D = t.getDescribe();
    if(!d.isUndeletable()){
        System.debug(t);
    }
}
```

Or if you're happy user of the RealForceExplorer:

[image]

This is probably not 100% truth - if I recall correctly you can delete an OpportunityLineItem, see it in Rec. Bin but cannot undelete it...

Answer (score 1):

You can see Quote Line Items but not Opportunity Line Items in the recycle bin.