# Only a few of the Deleted records are visible in Recycle Bin

Tags: recycle-bin

I have several records with isDeleted = true when I query using the workbench, but when I open my recycle Bin even the All Recycle Bin shown only a few records.
Why is this so?

Comment: Are all the records you are looking at of one type? See [Which objects do not go to the Recycle Bin upon deletion?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24282/which-objects-do-not-go-to-the-recycle-bin-upon-deletion).

Comment: Yes all are of type Account. However, I read this from the Salesforce help.
Choose My Recycle Bin from the drop-down list to view just the items you deleted. Administrators, and users with the “Modify All Data” permission, can choose All Recycle Bin to view all data that has been deleted for the entire organization. In Personal Edition, the All Recycle Bin option shows all of your deleted items.
I am assuming the above might be the reason for limited records getting displayed